# How to optimize the following snippet?

Tags: java, if-statement

The following snippet says the type based on name

```
public static List<String> LANGUAGES = Arrays.asList("js", "java", "html");
public static List<String> LIBRARIES = Arrays.asList("jquery", "ember");
public static List<String> BROWSERS = Arrays.asList("chrome", "safari", "mozilla");
public static List<String> MAIL = Arrays.asList("gmail", "yahoo");
public static List<String> EDITORS = Arrays.asList("vim", "vi", "notepad");

public static getType(String name) {

String type = null;
if(LANGUAGES.contains(name)) {
  type = "languages";
} else if(LIBRARIES.contains(name)) {
  type = "libraries";
} else if(BROWSERS.contains(name)) {
  type = "browsers";
} Else if (MAIL. contains (name)) {
  type = "mail";
}else if(EDITORS.contains(name)) {
  type = "editors";
}
return type
}
```

Thought of trying the same with switch statement. But switch doesn't provide option to check with list.contains in Java.

Is there any way to write the above snippet in a better way? Because the getType method keeps on growing with the new types added.

Comment: Hint: a `Map<String, String>` could contain the entire set of rules: if a key is something like `vi`, the value is e.g. `editors`. One lookup might be enough.

Comment: Side-note, if you are only checking for membership on your container, use a `Set` or `Collection`.

Comment: You can't initialize List like that

Comment: @GurV you are right.. I have edited my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to use map for this:

```
public static List<String> LANGUAGES = {"js", "java", "html"};
public static List<String> LIBRARIES = {"jquery", "ember"};
public static List<String> BROWSERS = {"chrome", "safari", "mozilla"};
public static List<String> MAIL = {"gmail", "yahoo"};
public static List<String> EDITORS = {"vim", "vi", "notepad"};

private static Map<String, String> categories= new HashMap<>;
static {
      // build the above map:
      LANGUAGES.forEach(e -> categories.put(e, "languages"));
      LIBRARIES.forEach(e -> categories.put(e, "libraries"));
      ...
}

public static getType(String name) {
      return categories.get(name);
}
```